# Hide vertical scrollbar in Iframe in IE9

Tags: html-table, internet-explorer-9, scrollbar

I have to embed a iframe within one of the rows of the table.I am able to do it but the problem I am facing is that the iframe is coming  with a vertical scroll bar. I tried to find the solutions and included every bit of css I could to remove the scrollbar but still not able to do so. I am using IE9.

```
$('<tr id = "pqr" ><td colspan="8">' + '<iframe src="../../priceBand3/views/priceBand.html" id="IframeId" style="width:1100px;overflow-y:hidden !hidden;scrolling:no;seamless:seamless"></iframe>' + '</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrolling` is not a style attribute but an attribute of `iframe` itself.

```
$('<tr id = "pqr" ><td colspan="8">' + '<iframe src="../../priceBand3/views/priceBand.html" id="IframeId" width="1100" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>' + '</td></tr>');
```